# how can we identify that company is legal not a scam?

Tags: job-search, company-policy, job-description

How can we judge/ identify that the company we are apply for a job is legally working in USA. This Company is valid. 
Is there any web site to check the history of company web site? The Main point is how can we trust this company?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're going to have to flesh out your question and improve your wording if you hope to get an answer ...

Comment: Reword your question to be more specific about what you mean by "legally".  Legally incorporated? Engaged in illegal activities? Licensed by a regulating authority? Insured? Be more clear about what specifically concerns you about the company (don't name names), and someone out there will be able to help you with some sources you can use to check things out.

Comment: In Florida you can check in this page http://sunbiz.org/search.html if they are legally registered, I think every state has their own website

Comment: If you have any reason to suspect that an offer is a scam, it probably is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if they have a website, you can go to [archive.org](http://archive.org) and see how far back it goes and what it looked like. A professional company will not have a website, which looks like it was created as a high school computer class project, past mid 90's

BBB as mentioned is a good reference but since some companies has no benefit from BBB, they might not be members but if they are in retails or service to public type businesses, they should be and missing membership would be a big red flag.

If you know a corporate recruiter with access to Lexis Nexis database, it has invaluable data but since memberships are expensive, I highly doubt you can find anyone with this membership. Maybe a few lucky people reading this, may benefit from it.

Last but not the least, type company name followed by words, scam, rip-off, illegal, etc. and make few searches. If there is anything remotely negative about them, will show up.

Answer (score 2):

You can check their phone number, website if they have one, physical address, or try and find out if their company is registered.

If you think something fishy is going on then be extra careful, because it doesn't cost two cents for a scammer to pretend they represent a legitimate company that does exist.

Comment: And there have been scammers who invented additional websites to provide apparent references so remember that an endorsement oif an unknown from an unknown is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

If it's really such a question you should definitely use a combination of circumstances to validate a business. Having a valid phone number and physical address is a good indicator but not the whole picture.

If they have a website, you can try to [find out who registered the domain](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Out-Who-Registered-a-Domain) and see if it looks reputable enough. At the same time, the website itself should look professional enough.

Company reviews like BBB, Google, Yelp or what have you should have some indication that regardless if they're a good corporation or not, they're at least legitimate.

If they're registered as a corporation, LLC, etc. the office of the secretary of state should also be able to tell you if they are a properly registered company.

If they're publicly traded and file an SEC form 10-K, you can broadly find a tax ID called an EIN, but you should also be able to speak to payroll and obtain this number with a good reason (I don't think a company would *want* to go ahead and say "we're shady," but they also have to worry about identity theft so this is a long shot!)

In some cases just like with taxes, web domain or corp/llc registrations, some businesses will also have to be registered to specific federal bodies based on the type of work they do, and a phone call to said agency may shed some light on the legitimacy of the suspect business (so think FDA, finCEN, etc.).

All else fails, you can also go to the physical address for the business and scope them out yourself if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

The standard is to check that they have a **[DUNS number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Universal_Numbering_System)**.  It includes all companies in the US and EU, and is used by the United Nations and US federal government.

DUNS ensures that the business exists, and for a fee you can get a credit rating that includes active lawsuits in the US against the company--which would show if a vendor has filed suit for non-payment.

There are still many ways for a company to be a scam, but the credit report typically goes down quickly if the company isn't paying bills.

The Better Business Bureau does not necessarily list all businesses.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Better Business Bureau's rating on them.  If they have none: RED FLAG.

Also check "The Ripoff Report"

Type in their phone number and see what comes up on whocallsme or other websites.

Without more information, that's the best I can do.

Comment: The BBB thing isn't an accurate way to judge a business. Many businesses don't have BBB ratings (including the three I run) and in no way should it raise a red flag. If it had a poor rating, yes, but no rating is not a red flag. Many businesses don't bother registering with the BBB because they are not end-customer facing, there are other rating groups for B2B like Dunn & Bradstreet. I would not say that the BBB rating (or lack there-of) is a gauge of a reputable US company.

Comment: Second the lack of a BBB report not mattering.  I just checked my employer.  They've been around a decade.  No BBB report, no website beyond a Facebook page. Since virtually all their customers are other businesses in an industry where they must seek out business rather than business coming to them I don't find myself at all surprised.